# Converting time series to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, time-series

I have a time series with monthly columns and 30 rows for years with values in that I am trying to convert into a data frame. The problem is that when do it, the code inverts the values of the columns and the rows and I don't know how to stop this from happening. The code I am using is this:

```
data.frame(matrix(data = spi_ts_12,nrow = 30, ncol = 12))
```

A piece of the original time series looks like this:

```
spi_ts_12
            Jan          Feb          Mar          Apr          May          Jun          Jul
1            NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
2  -0.072716360  0.339857586  0.536179857  1.224146721  1.066812903  0.903041290  1.495927052
3   1.874687022  1.842638334  1.822894060  1.289273431  0.931882600  1.046589831  0.459839100
4   0.924828112  1.130954986  1.156797627  1.417022228  1.888921382  1.528365517  1.260246481
5   0.072198409 -0.406376694 -0.510880719 -0.954572806 -1.606281038 -1.019738846 -1.041013230
```

but something like this I what I get with the code

```
data.frame(matrix(data = spi_ts_12,nrow = 30, ncol = 12))
            X1          X2          X3          X4           X5           X6          X7
1           NA  0.45983910 -0.68314309 -0.71271456  0.573582434 -0.262227248  0.64884425
2           NA  0.14786275 -0.77433962 -0.22896126  0.532289278 -0.238559810  0.65724941
3           NA  0.20082562 -0.32444436 -0.57079826  0.642000515 -0.323273642  1.23843136
4           NA  0.13612275 -0.40369149 -0.34258291  1.159903215 -1.346109264  1.89273535
```

Comment: are you sure your data has 12 columns as specified in the `matrix`call?

Comment: Please show your input using `dput` as instructed at the top of the [tag:r] tag page so that we know precisely what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about an `xts` time series? The other answers are overthinking this to the nth degree while overlooking the real issue - `data.frame` is not a conversion function.

You want `as.data.frame()`- `xts` defines an `as.data.frame.xts` S3 method.

Comment: yeah I realized that I was not using a conversion function. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the data will be analyzed in subsequent steps, it may be appropriate to convert it to a narrow format tidy data frame, where each row is a unique combination of `year` and `month`.

One can convert the data to a narrow format tidy data set by adding a `year` column and using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. We start with data provided in the question as follows. Since we don't know the start year, we assume the first row is for the year 2001.

```
textData <- "rowId            Jan          Feb          Mar          Apr          May          Jun          Jul
1            NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
2  -0.072716360  0.339857586  0.536179857  1.224146721  1.066812903  0.903041290  1.495927052
3   1.874687022  1.842638334  1.822894060  1.289273431  0.931882600  1.046589831  0.459839100
4   0.924828112  1.130954986  1.156797627  1.417022228  1.888921382  1.528365517  1.260246481
5   0.072198409 -0.406376694 -0.510880719 -0.954572806 -1.606281038 -1.019738846 -1.041013230"
df <- read.table(text = textData,header=TRUE)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tidyData <- df %>% mutate(year = 2000 + rowId) %>% 
     select(!contains("rowId")) %>% 
     pivot_longer(-year,names_to="month",values_to="value")
head(tidyData,10)
```

...and the first few rows of output:

```
> head(tidyData,10)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
    year month   value
   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1  2001 Jan   NA     
 2  2001 Feb   NA     
 3  2001 Mar   NA     
 4  2001 Apr   NA     
 5  2001 May   NA     
 6  2001 Jun   NA     
 7  2001 Jul   NA     
 8  2002 Jan   -0.0727
 9  2002 Feb    0.340 
10  2002 Mar    0.536
```

At this point each row consists of one value per month.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution might be `byrow = TRUE`.

Comparing your two datasets, it seems, that the first row in dataset 1 is now in the first column of dataset 2. `matrix` is reading the values in `spi_ts_12` columnwise, if you want them to read rowwise you need to set `byrow = TRUE`.

Here is an example:

```
m <- 1:10

# That's what your code does
data.frame(matrix(m, ncol = 2, nrow = 5))
X1 X2
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
5  5 10

# That's what it should do
data.frame(matrix(m, ncol = 2, nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE))
X1 X2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  5  6
4  7  8
5  9 10
```